# why is there an invisible line on the top of the cup that is preventing the ball from falling in?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

i have the cup set to passive and the ball set to active and made sure they were both meshes but it still would not work.[image: This is when i pressed play all the ball was doing was shaking in place]

Comment: try to change the collision shape from "convex hull" to "mesh"

Answer (score 3):

Rigid bodies have collision parameters that by default defined the collision shape as a convex hull around the shape.

As your object is hollow (concave), you need to change this parameter to mesh, so that the collision shape matches the mesh as it is.

The reason of this parameter is to optimize collision calculations when accuracy is not needed. Convex hull is generally a good compromize.

[More information here in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties/collisions.html).

[image]

The source (second parameter) allows to define if the mesh is taken into account as it is or considering the modifiers that are applied to it. By default, this is the mesh with its eventual deform modifiers (or shape keys).